# QObject.inherits(className) works strange in PyQt5

Tags: python, inheritance, pyqt, pyqt5

`QObject.inherits(className)` does work different in `PyQt5` than in `PyQt4` and `PySide`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
#from PySide import QtGui
#from PyQt4 import QtGui

QtWidgets = QtGui

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    pass

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
w = MyWidget()
print(w.inherits("MyWidget"))
```

In `PyQt5` it prints `False`, while in `PyQt4` and `PySide` (uncomment the second or third line and comment the first one) it prints `True`. Why is that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this behaviour in PyQt-5.7.

It seems to be a bug, because the same problem does not appear in the [latest development snapshot](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5) (PyQt5_gpl-5.7.1.dev1611251257). The only solution is to wait until PyQt-5.7.1 is released.